# The set of all the rotations of a plane around multiple points contained in it doesn't form a group.

Tags: group-theory

I'm reading the book "An introduction to the theory of Groups" by P.S. Alexandroff and in one of his examples he says that the group of all the rotations of a plane around a given (fixed) point forms a group that is isomorphic to the rotations of a circle over a plane, around it's center.
 This is quite easy to visualize.

However, a later exercise asks the reader to prove that the set of rotations of a plane around multiple points (contained in it) doesn't form a group.

I couldn't come up with any counter-examples and I'd really appreciate hints and insights about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The composition of a (for instance) rotation by $\pi/2$ about the origin and then a rotation by $\pi/2$ about $(1,0)$ is not again a rotation about a point, so this set of actions is not closed under multiplication.

Proof: The two operations $A,B$ I suggested above send the point $(1,0)$ first to $(0,1)$, and then to $(1-\sqrt{2},0)$. A rotation $C$ of the plane that will send $(1-\sqrt{2},0)$ back to $(1,0)$ is a rotation of $(2k+1)\pi$ about the midpoint $\left(\frac{2-\sqrt{2}}{2},0\right)$, and it is easy to check that these three rotations will not send (choose a point here, say the origin) back to itself, so $A\circ B$ has no inverse.

Comment: How can you prove that that composition itself is not a rotation around a point?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD It is a translation, in particular it has no fixed points, while all rotations fix their center.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD Either write out the equations for the two transformations and compute the composition, or close your eyes and visualize the situation, or take sheet of paper lying flat on your desk and physically rotate it.  (I prefer the second option.)

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD I added a mostly complete proof, but it is less elucidating to me than just spending a couple of moments visualizing what's going on. Also note that I didn't really take any time to make clever choices here. Maybe rotations by $\pi$ about these two points will be easier to see.

Comment: @EricTressler Sorry, I wasn't clear. I think I do understand what's going on, and why it isn't a rotation, I just wanted to wrap everything up with a way to formally prove that. Thank you very much